# Javascript word game how to make function not replace element

Tags: javascript, function

**Question has been answered**

I'm trying to make a small word game, 
and I already encountered a small problem I couldn't figure out.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Word Game</title>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="StyleSheet" href="style.css" />

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Word Game</h1>
    <div id="board">

        <p>Do you want to play? (yes/no)</p>
    </div>
    <div id="form">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <input type="input" id="userTxt"></input>
                <button type="button" id="btn" onclick = "post()">Send</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
#board {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
#board p {
    padding-left: 3%;
}
#form {
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}
input {
margin: auto;
display: block;
}
button {
display: block;
clear: both;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var post = function() {
    var userTxt = document.getElementById("userTxt");
    var boardId = document.getElementById("board");

    var text = userTxt.value;
    boardId.innerHTML = "<p>- " + text + "</p>";
}
```

Now, the function works alright. But,
if you check the code you'll see that, for example if you'd write "p" in the box and submit it and then for example "e", the "p" will CHANGE to "e" and not add a new `<p></p>` to the board. How do I make it add a new element, and not replace the old element?

Comment: Just concat to the value that is already there.

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=`. `a += 1` is equivalent to `a = a + 1`;

Comment: But seeing that there is already a string in the `<p></p>` (the question) at the start of the game, you will need to check if the value already there is the question. If its question then replace, otherwise concat.

Answer (score 0):

Try to just concat the innertext:-

```
   var post = function() {
        var userTxt = document.getElementById("userTxt");
        var boardId = document.getElementById("board");

        var text = userTxt.value;
        boardId.innerText = boardId.innerText.trim();
        boardId.innerText += " - " + text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the html to add an id directly to your `<p>` tag for ease of access.

```
<div id="board">
    <p id="text-container">Do you want to play? (yes/no)</p>
</div>
```

And change the function as this

```
 function post() {
    var userTxt = document.getElementById("userTxt");
    var boardId = document.getElementById("text-container");

    var text = userTxt.value;

    if (boardId.textContent == "Do you want to play? (yes/no)") {
        boardId.textContent = "- " + text;
    } else {
        boardId.textContent += text;
    }

}
```

Try it here on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ5vu/2/).